# Rails: Ask user authentication before CanCan access denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I want to show login form instead of cancan access denied flash message. this is my controller

```
#app/controllers/oferts_controller.rb
class OfertsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_ofert, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  load_and_authorize_resource :only => [:new, :edit, :destroy] 
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]
  # GET /oferts
  # GET /oferts.json
  def index
    @oferts = Ofert.areactive
  end

  # GET /oferts/1
  # GET /oferts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /oferts/new
  def new
    @ofert = current_user.oferts.new
    @ofert.purchasing_group = PurchasingGroup.new
  end

  # GET /oferts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /oferts
  # POST /oferts.json
  def create
    ....
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /oferts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /oferts/1.json
  def update
  ....
  end

  # DELETE /oferts/1
  # DELETE /oferts/1.json
  def destroy
   ...
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_ofert
      @ofert = Ofert.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def ofert_params

      params.require(:ofert).permit(:title, :short_title, :description, :price, :normal_price, :ends_at, :ends_at_date, :ends_at_time)
    end
end
```

For some reason when I try to access an action that requires login, for example, "create", I only get the access denied message from CanCan, but Im not redirected to the login page as it should, since I have the :authenticate_user! before_filter in the controller.

How can prioritize the devise redirection to login page instead of the cancan access denied flash message?

Thanks

Update:
This is my Gemfile

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.9'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

gem 'money-rails', '~> 1.2.0'

gem 'money', '~> 6.5.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

gem 'foundation-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-rails', '~>4.3.0.0'
gem 'devise'
gem "cancan"
gem "rolify"
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2"
gem 'rails-i18n', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'whenever', :require => false
gem 'jquery-countdown-rails'
# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

group :development do
    # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
    gem 'spring'
    gem 'quiet_assets', '~>1.1'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0'
  gem 'rspec-expectations'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.3.0'
  gem 'capybara-email'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 2.7.0'
  gem 'rspec-its'
  gem 'rspec-activemodel-mocks', '~> 1.0.1'
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, here's the conventional and DRY way to do it:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  # ...

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied, with: :access_denied

  # ...

  private

  def access_denied(exception)
    store_location_for :user, request.path
    redirect_to user_signed_in? ? root_path : new_user_session_path, alert: exception.message
  end

end
```

This will store the requested location in a session and render `Devise` login form if user is currently not signed in. Stored location will trigger redirect to the requested location after successful sign in.

Placing the code in `ApplicationController` will define such behavior globally.

If you don't need this for the every controller, you are free to put `rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied, with: :access_denied` line where you want it, `OfertsController` in your case. You'll also need to list `access_denied` method as `protected` rather than `private`.

Comment: Yes you are right I did it like that long time ago. jeje

Answer (score 4):

Since `load_and_authorize_resource` adds a `before_action` to the controller, I would suggest inversing:

```
load_and_authorize_resource :only => [:new, :edit, :destroy]
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]
```

like:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]
load_and_authorize_resource :only => [:new, :edit, :destroy]
```

Each call to `before_filter` or `before_action`, it adds methods to a queue and they are called in FIFO (First In First Out) order at runtime.

I would also suggest using `before_action` instead of `before_filter` because as per [Rails 4.2 Release Notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html), the *_filter family of methods is discouraged as it has been removed from documentation and it will be deprecated in a future release of Rails and will eventually be removed.

Comment: Well I did what you suggested, now my controller has 
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]
load_and_authorize_resource :only => [:new, :edit, :destroy]

But it did not change it's behavior, still shows only the flash message of cancan instead of redirect to login page... =/

Comment: Can you tell me which version of Rails you're running as well as edit your original post and include the Gemfile's contents? If it doesn't contain the version of both Devise and CanCan, can you let me know which version of both you're running?

Comment: Im running the last stable versions of cancan and Devise, and Rails 4, I added the Gemfile to the post.

Comment: Ho this is embarast, I forgot to restar my heroku server, now it works!! thanks for take the time to answer =D